# Proof or a hint for a fact about definition of left invariant metrics on Lie groups and examples for that

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Is there a reference contains the proof or a hint of the following fact about definition of left invariant metrics on Lie groups ( with constant curvature or not) and examples for that?

**Fact:** *

> A  left invariant pseudo-Riemannian metric $g$ on a group $G$
> corresponds  exactly to a  transitive free isometric actions of $G$ on
> pseudo-Riemannian manifolds $(X, \sigma)$.
> Let $M= M^{p, q}(c)$
> be the universal pseudo-Riemannian space of constant curvature $c$ (it
> is complete and simply connected).  A left invariant pseudo-Riemannian
> metric of constant sectional curvature $c$ on $G$ corresponds to   a
> representation   $\rho: G \to Isom (M^{p, q)}(c))$ and a
> $\rho(G)$-orbit  $\mathcal O \subset M^{p, q)}(c)$ which is open.  The
> representation $\rho$ has to be locally injective, i.e. an immersion.
> (The $\rho(G)$-action may have  other non-open orbits). The pair
> $(\rho, \mathcal O)$ is uniquely determined up to conjugacy in $Isom(M^{p, q)}(c))$.

- 

Comment: Where is this from? There are much simpler definitions of a left invariant metric on a Lie group. Is such an abstract one really necessary?

Comment: Yes I gree, but for me I compelled to understand it very well, and for the propose of it it may open a way  somehow will weaker the notion of LIM, and it can used for classification of LIM of constant curvature.

Comment: If you want to understand this, I suggest breaking it down into smaller chunks and making sure you understand exactly what each chunk means. Then slowly reassemble it. And see if you can make it sound simpler. I'm skeptical that this is the easiest way to say it. And most advances in research come from viewing something from a simple rather than overly sophisticated perpsective.